# Google Chrome Close Tabs on Idle

Tags: google-chrome

It be nice to close tabs on idle with a whitelist that leaves certain tabs open like mail or grooveshark..

Any thoughtss?

Answer (score 3):

The [Tab Wrangler](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/egnjhciaieeiiohknchakcodbpgjnchh) extension will close unused tabs after a specified amount of time, and can whitelist tabs both at the tab level, or at the url level (eg, whitelist any tabs that are with the url mail.google.com/*)